# How to define a nested lists

Tags: haskell, types

Trying to solve the Exercise 7 at [this page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/1_to_10) I want to define the data type to write some value like:

```
(List [Elem 1, List [Elem 2, List [Elem 3, Elem 4], Elem 5]])
```

Nested list, any length, any depth.

I tried with this code:

```
data List a = Elem a | List [List a]
```

but it doesn't compile:

```
Parse error: naked expression at top level
```

How can it be done?

Comment: Please post a complete code sample that produces the error message you're getting. Just `data List a = Elem a | List [List a]` will *not* produce that error message (or any other error message for that matter).

Comment: @sepp2k Yes, it even lets me do `let b = List [Elem 1, List [Elem 2, List [Elem 3, Elem 4], Elem 5]] :: List Integer` in ghci.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of a file containing this:

```
data List a = Elem a | List [List a]
(List [Elem 1, List [Elem 2, List [Elem 3, Elem 4], Elem 5]])
```

Try a file containing this:

```
data List a = Elem a | List [List a]
sampleListValue = List [Elem 1, List [Elem 2, List [Elem 3, Elem 4], Elem 5]]
```

By the way, a very similar type is also available [in the standard libraries](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Tree.html) (I know you don't want to use this as it's a learning exercise, but keep in mind that it's available).